# Using SwiftyJSON for subarray with Swift 3.1

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have a json data. I never use SwiftyJSON before. I am trying first time.

My json like this:

```
[
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "A",
  "SubNames": [
  {
    "SubId": 1,
    "SubName": "A1"
  },
  {
    "SubId": 2,
    "SubName": "A2"
  }]
},
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "B",
  "SubNames": [
  {
    "SubId": 1,
    "SubName": "B1"
  },
  {
    "SubId": 2,
    "SubName": "B2"
  }]
}
]
```

I can handle Name and append a array. But I can't handle SubNames. I tried somethings but doesn't work unfortunately. I want to append SubNames a array. This array will be like this:

```
[["A1","A2"],["B1","B2"]]
```

I use this code:

```
let json = JSON(data: data!)
for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {                
self.names.append(subJson["Name"].stringValue
}
```

Comment: show the model you have prepared for this json structure using swiftyjson.

Comment: @AnilKumar I edited my question. This enough ? Thank you.

Comment: @AnilKumar sorry I dont understand can you explain a little?

Comment: you should make a two model for this, one model which contains 
"Id": intType,
 "Name": stringType,
  "SubNames": [subNames]

and the other is subNames which contains
"SubId": intType,
    "SubName": stringType

Comment: @AnilKumar thank you for explain. I didn't use before model therefore I dont know how can I use. If you have a time can you show me? or you can give me a source link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to access those fields, and you shouldn't do `data!` here

```
guard let `data` = data else {
    //no data handling
    return 
}
let dataArray = JSON(data: data).arrayValue
var arrayOfAllSubnames: [[String]] = [[]]

for object in dataArray {
    var arrayOfSubnames: [String] = []
    if let subnames = object["SubNames"].array {
        for subname in subnames {
            //here you get `"SubId": 2, "SubName": "B2"` object
            let subnameValue = subname["SubName"].stringValue
            arrayOfSubnames.append(subnameValue)
        }
    }
    arrayOfAllSubnames.append(arrayOfSubnames)
}
```

Comment: thank you. But my problem collect in array SubName, like this: [["A1","A2"],["B1","B2"]]

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

1) First declare sub name array.

```
var subNameArray: [[String]] = []
```

2) you can access and store this objects as below.

```
let json = JSON(data: data!).arrayValue

for item in json {

   var tempArray: [String] = []

   let name = item["Name"].stringValue

   for subNameItem in items["SubNames"].arrayValue {
     tempArray.append(subNameItem["SubName"].stringValue)
   } 
  subNameArray.append(tempArray)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but first @JuicyFruit answered. I will accept him, sorry.

Comment: Not an issue, Happy with you got your final answer. Keep On Questioning